# How to accept application/csp-report as json in express and bodyParser?

Tags: javascript, json, express, content-type, body-parser

I'm trying to write a middleware to accept CSP report from browser. Browser issues `application/csp-report` as `Content-Type`. The request being posted is JSON format. Currently I use `bodyParser.text` to accept that Content-type. But I thought there might be a better way to accept `application/csp-report` as JSON in bodyParser.

Here's what I'm doing right now.

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.text({type: 'application/csp-report'}));
```

My question is how do I accept JSON request payload with `Content-Type` `application-csp-report`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since it is actually JSON you can inform Express of that fact like this:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/csp-report'}));
```

Note however some browsers use `application/csp-report`, some `application/json` so I set both:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/json'}));
app.use(bodyParser.json({type: 'application/csp-report'}));
```

If it helps I've code for a (very simple) Node Report service here: https://www.tunetheweb.com/security/http-security-headers/csp/

Answer (score 5):

In addition to @Barry's answer, you can set endpoint path more specifically:

```
app.use('/report-violation', bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/json' }));
app.use('/report-violation', bodyParser.json({ type: 'application/csp-report' }));
app.use('/report-violation', (req, res) => {
  // handle req.body
});
```